# API call is able to return 200 response but not 403 in Flutter

Tags: flutter

```
Future<dynamic> scanDurian(String durianTag, String durianGrade) async {
  // Retrieve tokens from SharedPreferences
  final accessToken = await AuthService.getAccessToken();
  final refreshToken = await AuthService.getRefreshToken();
  // Save cookies to the cookie jar
  List<Cookie> cookies = [
    Cookie('accessToken', accessToken!),
    Cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken!),
  ];
  cookieJar.saveFromResponse(Uri.parse(baseUrl), cookies);

  // Attach the cookie jar to the Dio instance
  dio.interceptors.add(CookieManager(cookieJar));

  try {
    final response = await dio.post(
      '$baseUrl/durian/scan-durian',
      options: Options(
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
        },
      ),
      data: {
        'durian_tag': durianTag,
        'durian_grade': durianGrade,
      },
    );
//when detected 200 it will run the first if
//when detecting 403, app crashes
//console logs return nothing related in the statement of being 403
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      final responseData = response.data;
      return {'success': true, 'data': responseData};
    }
else if(response.statusCode == 403) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      return {'success': true, 'message': 'pass'};
    }
    else{
     print(response.statusCode);
      return {'success': false, 'message': 'Failed to scan durian'};

}

  } on DioException catch (e) {
    print(e);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
}
```

Im trying to do error handling on statusCode == 403, however the case is it can only return 200 and return the success message.
I tried cross check whether the error code is null(possibility of not being passed from backend) or 403 but seems like it will only result into app crashes.

Note: Im using NGROK to broadcast the API using physical mobile devices trying to handle **QR CODE SCAN**

I am expecting that the return of the response status code to return 403 (I did check backend they are in the same layer of error handling)

```
if {
       ......  
            return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Updated' });
        }else{
            return res.status(403).json({ message: 'already been updated' });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<dynamic> scanDurian(String durianTag, String durianGrade) async {
  // Retrieve tokens from SharedPreferences
  final accessToken = await AuthService.getAccessToken();

  try {
    final response = await dio.post(
      '$baseUrl/durian/scan-durian',
      options: Options(
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
        },
      ),
      data: {
        'durian_tag': durianTag,
        'durian_grade': durianGrade,
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final responseData = response.data;
      return {'success': true, 'data': responseData};
    } else {
      // Handle specifically for 403 Forbidden
      if (response.statusCode == 403) {
        return {'success': false, 'message': 'Forbidden access'};
      }
      // Handle other error codes
      return {'success': false, 'message': 'Failed to scan durian'};
    }
  } on DioError catch (e) {
    // Catch DioException for network-related issues
    if (e.response?.statusCode == 403) {
      return {'success': false, 'message': 'Forbidden access'};
    }
    // Handle other DioException scenarios
    return {'success': false, 'message': 'Network error occurred'};
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle other exceptions
    return {'success': false, 'message': 'Unexpected error occurred'};
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem persists, and i tried printing this to check whether it has been passed but the console did not print anything, not even for 403. 

    
print(response.statusCode);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final responseData = response.data;
      return {'success': true, 'data': responseData};
    } else {
      // Handle specifically for 403 Forbidden
      if (response.statusCode == 403) {
        print('check');
        return {'success': false, 'message': 'Forbidden access'};
      }

Comment: In the log of Ngrok it does show 403 and 200. When using the same cases of checking it doesn't seem to comply or return the status code

Comment: Problem solved, apparently Dio treats non-2xx status codes are considered successful responses, and they are not treated as errors.